# Extend ActiveRecord::Base with two column getters

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working with a legacy database schema which defines the equivalents to Rails' created_at and updated_at as:

> ```
> # MySQL
> createDate MEDIUMTEXT
> modifiedDate MEDIUMTEXT
> ```

These columns exist for nearly all the 20 or so tables in the database, and I've written the getter code for it already,

```
  def createDate
    DateTime.strptime(read_attribute(:createDate), "%s")
  end

  def modifiedDate
    DateTime.strptime(read_attribute(:createDate), "%s")
  end
```

How can I "extend" ActiveRecord::Base so that all my models get these two methods?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a module and include it in ActiveRecord::Base:

```
module LegacyTimestamps
  def createDate
    DateTime.strptime(read_attribute(:createDate), "%s")
  end

  def modifiedDate
    DateTime.strptime(read_attribute(:modifiedDate), "%s")
  end      
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, LegacyTimestamps
```

It's also possible to include such module only in some models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include LegacyTimestamps
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Which file would you suggest I put this in? An initializer is my first guess.

Comment: Actually this raised an error: createDate is defined by ActiveRecord (ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError).. ideas?

Comment: what version of rails are you running?

Comment: 3.2. I turned it into a class LegacyTimestamp < ActiveRecord::Base now and just subclass that one.